# Java, Verificação de vencimento de IPVA de acordo com a placa do carro

Tags: java, mysql

Tenho que fazer a verificação do vencimento de IPVA, mas não faço de ideia de como faze-la , já que todo ano muda e para uma data de vencimento existem vários finais de placas.

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao SOpt, eu sugiro que vc faça um Tour http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour antes de fazer uma pergunta.

Answer (score 2):

O calendário de vencimentos do IPVA não é decidido de acordo com um algoritmo rígido e bem-definido, e sim decidido de acordo com negociações e conveniências entre as secretarias de fazendas, os DETRANs e outros órgãos públicos e então publicado por meio de portarias.

Desta forma, o melhor que você pode fazer é cadastrar as datas de vencimento em algum banco de dados e então consultá-lo utilizando o final da placa para encontrar a data de vencimento correta. E é importante que alguém fique de olho nas portarias emitidas pelas secretarias de fazenda e DETRANs para estar sempre alimentando o banco de dados com estas informações.